# Align form controls Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was my form labels to appear to the left of my textboxes (labels all right aligned and textboxes all left aligned).

Right now they are all appearing on top of my textboxes:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <label for="test">Test</label>
        <input id="test" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <label for="more">More</label>
        <input id="more" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you are already using Bootstrap - get benefits of its Grid system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using bootstrap's grid. Here is a link to [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/KJk6WY442s).

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="test">Test</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="test" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="more">More</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="more" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Great! Have a look at the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Those examples will help you understand how it bootstrap works.

Answer (score 1):

Without your CSS I won't be able to tell for sure, but try:

```
label {
    display: inline;
}
```

It would be helpful if you provided the CSS as well as the HTML.

Comment: label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

Changing it to block does not change anything

Answer (score 1):

Answer / example is right in the bootstrap examples:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

You can match your form structure to it.